# как генерить xml

Tags: php, xml

Что я делаю не так подскажите пожалуйста((((

```
<?php
//define( '_VALID_', 1 );
defined( '_VALID_' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
$dir='/var/www/html/build';
//require_once( $dir.'/config.php' );
//$Config_db_nls_lang='AL32UTF8';
//require_once( $Config_absolute_path.'/main/db.php' );
//require_once( $dir.'/main/db.php' );
//$in_fname=$Config_absolute_path."/sql/".$tmpls;
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Aqtobe'); //'Europe/Moscow'
    require_once 'xls/PHPExcel.php';
$query="select * from zrdt.report where id=".$report_id;
$database->setQuery($query);
$database->loadObject($report);     
$query="select f.full_name f_name,d.*
     from zrdt.report_detail d,zrdt.filial f where f.id=d.filial_id
           and report_id=".$report_id." and report_result_id=".$report_result_id."
          order by filial_id";
    $database->setQuery($query);$rows = $database->loadObjectList();

//echo  $query;exit;
        $database->setQuery( $query );
        $rows = $database->loadObjectList();

    $xml_data_begin=<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
   <Author>Nurzhaubay A.N.</Author>
   <LastAuthor>Radmin</LastAuthor>
   <Created>1980-02-15T00:00:01Z</Created>
   <Version>12.00</Version>
  </DocumentProperties>
  <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
   <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
  </ExcelWorkbook>
<Worksheet ss:Name="Result">
  <Table x:FullColumns="1"   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0"><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Дата обхода</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Наименование филиала</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Наименование региона</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Город</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Улица</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Дом</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Корпус</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Квартира</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Ф.И.О.:</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">моб.№</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Конкурент INTERNET</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Конкурент TV</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Конкурент MOBILE</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Результат обхода</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Лицевой счет</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Название пакета</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Примечание</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Дата создание</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Изменил(а)</Data></Cell></Row>
$xml_data_end=
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <Unsynced/>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>

    if (ob_get_level()) {ob_end_clean();}
//    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=employee.xml");
    echo $xml_data_begin;
    //echo iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8//IGNORE", $row['XML_CLOB']);
        echo '<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">';

        echo '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">'.mb_convert_encoding(_FILIALNAME, "utf-8","windows-1251").'</Data></Cell>';

        echo '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">'.mb_convert_encoding(_LTOWN_NAME, "utf-8","windows-
        echo "</Row>\n";
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        echo '<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">';

        echo '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">'.mb_convert_encoding(trim($row->F_NAME), "utf-8","windows-1251").'</Data></Cell>';
        echo '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">'.mb_convert_encoding(trim($row->TWN_NAME), "utf-8","windows-1251").'</Data></Cell>';

        echo "</Row>\n";
    }
    echo $xml_data_end;
    exit();
   if (ob_get_level()) {ob_end_clean();}
   $fname="$report->NAME (".date('Ymd_His', time()).")";
   $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
   header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$fname.'.xls"');
   header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
   $writer->save('php://output');

?>
```

Comment: вы подключили PHPExcel дак пользуйтесь им, зачем это рукоблудие с генерацией xml ?

Comment: просто у меня выходные данные с запроса очень большие. И я теряю время при выполнении его. Хотел через xml, чтоб он просто *выплюнул* его через echo